# For a cw-complex the pair $\left(X,X^n \right)$ is n-connected

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Hello I am currently self-learning about (algebraic-)topology using Hatchers book.
My definition of $n$-connected is that $\pi_k\left(X,X^n\right)=0$ for all $1\le k \le n$.
I do know about the cellular approximation theorem but how can I apply it here ? Is there any trick to show that any representative is homotopic to something with image in $X^n$ using cellular approximation ?

Would appreciate any help

Comment: In the proof of 4.12, Hatcher says to apply "cellular approximation to maps $(D^i, \partial D^i) \to (X, A)$ with $i \leq n$," under the assumption that $X-A$ only has cells of dimension greater than $n$. Can you clarify your question, in regards to this?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Sorry for my confusion. If I can apply cellular approximation on the pair $\left(D^i,\partial D^i \right)$ the result follows immediatly as the image would lie in the skeleton $X^i$ which doesn't intersect $X\setminus A$ for $i\le n $ in $A$. But the pair isn't a cw-pair. I mean $D^i$ is not a cell complex.

Comment: You can triangulate $D^i$ and make it a simplicial complex, so it can certainly be given the structure of a CW complex. For example, let $D^i$ be an $i$-simplex and then $\partial D^i$ is its $(i-1)$-skeleton. Or let $\partial D^i$ be an $(i-1)$-sphere (for example with one $0$-cell and one $(i-1)$-cell) and attach a single $i$-cell via the identity map $S^{i-1} \to S^{i-1}$ to make $D^i$: that's a CW structure.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Thanks that clarifies everything :)